Object files, static libraries and one-definition rule
Let's imagine I have a compilation line like the following:
gcc <flags...> -o a.out obj1.o obj2.o

where both obj1.o and obj2.o defines void f(int). I will get a multiple-definition error (violation of the one-definition-rule).
Ok, now, imagine the following:
gcc <flags...> -o a.out obj1.o -lstatic_lib

where both obj1.o and static_lib.a defines f(int). I know that a static library is a concatenation of .o files, and for every symbol pending to be solved, is found inside any of the .o files of the static library, then the whole .o that resolves that symbol will be linked into the binary, together with any other symbol that very same .o provides.
That behaviour makes me wonder. Imagine that static_lib.a consists of two objects, static_obj1.o and static_obj2.o, where static_obj1.o is who defines f(int). Since obj1.o already defines f(int) as well, the linker is not looking for it within static_lib.a, and so static_obj1.o won't be theoretically included, but, and this is the question:

What if obj2.o requires f2(int), who is defined also by static_obj1.o? Would the linker, after integrating static_obj1.o because of f2(int), issue a multiple definition warning because of f1(int) being now twice?

NOTE: I'm tagging both C and C++ because I guess the behaviour is the same for both in this regard. If it's not, please clarify, I'm very interested in knowing any behavioural difference. Also, if the behaviour is very different between gcc/clang/visual studio/linux/windows, please clarify. If the behaviour is roughly the same, then focus on gcc over linux.

Yes, it would fail to link due to multiple definitions. However, with C++ linkage there could be two functions with the same name but different name manglings (due to having different prototypes and/or being in different namespaces) and those would not clash with each other.

The language doesn't matter at all. It could be Rust, Fortran or Ada and the result will be exactly the same, the linker doesn't care. If it pulls the same symbol twice, you get a multiple definition error.

Note that the one definition rule applies to entities which don't appear in object files, (class types for example) and also does not require a diagnostic from a program which violates it. What you're asking about is how linkers typically handle multiply defined symbols, which isn't quite the same thing.

@n.m.couldbeanAI The language does matter from the programmer's point of view. C++ specifically has things like function and operator overloading. These features require some manner of name mangling internally. The programmer just doesn't see it. It's perfectly valid C++ to have void a() and void a (int n) inside the same namespace and translation unit. Name mangling will handle it.

@Lundin Being a C++ programmer for 30 years or so, I think I know a small part of C++ by now. void a() and void a (int n) are simply different entities to a C++ programmer, as different as int a() and int b(). What happens if the linker pulls in both? Nothing special in either case. The exact kind of compiler magic that makes the linker see them as different symbols is not important.

@n.m.couldbeanAI The OP notes "I'm tagging both C and C++ because I guess the behaviour is the same for both" which I just demonstrated clearly is not the case. The language matters, contrary to what you said in your first comment.

@Lundin I have no idea why you would say that. The behaviour of the liker doesn't change depending on what language the source program was written in. The linker either sees the same symbol pulled twice, or it doesn't. The fact that void a() and void a (int n) can co-exist and not conflict in C++ could be mildly interesting to someone who is not familiar with how C++ works, but to someone who does, it is obvious that these things are as unrelated as int a() and int A().

@n.m.couldbeanAI The point being that if you write the same thing in C, you get a compiler error, or in case they are placed in different translation units, weird linker errors. Or another situation: in case someone decides to write int a; int a; int a; on top of every source file in the project, then that's fine in C but perhaps not in another language.

@Lundin If you writhe the same thing in Fortran, you also get a compiler error. It's a different language with different rules. Why would you expect that a C++ program can be viewed as a C program?

@Lundin I guess the behaviour is the same for C/C++ assuming the symbols are exactly the same. I know C++ makes a mangling from entity/definition name to symbol name, but I'm focused at the "symbol level".


Would the linker, after integrating static_obj1.o because of f2(int), issue a multiple definition warning because of f1(int) being now twice?

Yes.

… one-definition rule…

This is not governed by the one-definition rule in C++ or the corresponding rule in C. In regard to this linking issue, those rules merely indicate that a conforming program will not contain multiple definitions. They do not govern what happens when linking with multiple definitions. For example:

The linker could issue an error message and not produce an executable. This is conforming behavior because we interpret the program requested by linking these multiple object modules together to have multiple definitions. Then the behavior is not defined by the language standard, so any behavior is conforming.
Hypothetically, the linker could choose one object module and form an executable containing only one definition of each symbol. Again, since the behavior is not defined by the language standard, any behavior is conforming. Alternately, we could interpret the request to the linker to be a request to form a program with only one definition of the symbol, resulting in a program that does conform to the language standard. The standards are silent with regard to how we use linkers and other tools to link translation units together, so various interpretations of these interactions are possible.

